# How can you take a picture using the front camera on a tablet or slate PC?

Tags: wpf, windows-7, camera, windows-8

Is it possible to take a picture from the front camera on a Windows 7/8 slate using WPF?

Comment: Please post that last as a separate question, since it's unrelated (it'll also need a fair bit more detail about your requirements)

Comment: Thank you for the edits.  I guess I'll ask the driver's license question after I find out if it's possible to take picture with the camera using WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the VideoCaptureElement control in my [WPF MediaKit library](http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/). It should have everything you need for showing a webcam in WPF and/or getting snapshots. [(copy from here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167566/should-i-use-winforms-or-wpf-for-taking-pics-with-webcam)